# Unable to display query results using Order By. Is something wrong with the PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to order some rows based between 2 dates in the descending value of consumption = $issue_morn+$issue_noon+$issue_night

```
 <?php
                $date1="";
                $date2="";
                $item="";
             if(!empty($_POST['datepicker1'])&&!empty($_POST['datepicker2']))
            {
            $date1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['datepicker1']));
            $date2 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['datepicker2']));
            if(empty($_POST['item']))
            {    
            $sth = $conn->prepare('Select * From inventory where date between :date1 and :date2 order by consumption DESC');
            $sth->execute(array(':date1'=>$date1,':date2'=>$date2));}
            else
            {
            $item=$_POST['item'];
            $sth=$conn->prepare('Select * From inventory where item=:item AND date between :date1 and :date2 order by consumption DESC');
             $sth->execute(array(':date1'=>$date1,':date2'=>$date2,':item'=>$item));
            }
            $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
            foreach ($data as $row ){
                if($row['date']!="")
        {?>
```

But the values for EACH DAY are showing in descending order. I want the rows to be in the order of descending consumption irrespective of the date. How do I do that?

Comment: Sounds strange, maybe you could provide some test data in form of a CSV export for us to play around with?

Comment: Why is it strange?

Comment: Because in your query you are ordering by consumption, so it seems strange that it would return the results ordered by something else.

Comment: Is `consumption` a real column in `inventory` or a calculated one?

Comment: if we could have "inventory" tabel schema and some test data will be great!

Comment: @ADyson Similar is not same. I'm asking a different question here.

Comment: @VineetBasantani yes but you posted the inventory schema there. that's why I'm linking to it, in case it would help with this issue. Seems like you maybe solved the other question yourself since you now have the consumption calculated field in addition to the others

Comment: Yes, it got solved by having consumption as a table column and its value = $issue_morn+$issue_noon+$issue_night.

Comment: But it's not sorting consumption wise irrespective of the date. It is sorting wrt consumption but date wise. For each date, it's sorted wrt consumption